# Clip NetCDF files by shapefile

Tags: shapefile, clip, netcdf

I have 7000 nc4 files and I need to clip netCDF files based on a shapefile, but
I have a problem with rasterio. After I run this code, I got the error:

> #AttributeError: module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'features'

```
shapefile = 'polbnda_sau.shp'

sf = geopandas.read_file(shapefile)
shape_mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask(sf.iloc[0],
                                      out_shape=(len(ndvi.y), len(ndvi.x)),
                                      transform=ndvi.geobox.transform,
                                      invert=True)
shape_mask = xarray.DataArray(shape_masj , dims=("y", "x"))

file_list = sorted(glob.glob("C:\\Sample_to_analysis_netcdf\\DATA\\*.nc4"))

for file in file_list:
    nc_file = xarray.open_dataset(file)
    masked_netcdf_file = nc_file.where(shape_mask == True, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `rasterio.features` explicitly as a module:

```
>>> import rasterio
>>> rasterio.features
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'features'
```

but...

```
>>> import rasterio.features
>>> rasterio.features
<module 'rasterio.features' from '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/features.py'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I think you can do that by using the combination of "regionmask" and 'xarray' in python. I followed these steps:

1. **Store the geometry from geopandas to another variable** In your case,
   (polyfile = sf.geometry[0]) where geometry = [0,1,2..] depend upon number of polygons.
2. **Create a region objects**, region_object = regionmask.Regions([polyfile])
3. **xarray to open netcdf file** (ds = xr.open_dataset(r'abc.nc')) or (ds = xr.open_mfdataset(r'*.nc')).
4. **Creating mask** (mask = region_object.mask(ds.isel(time = 0), lat_name = 'lat', lon_name = 'lon')
5. **place the mask over overall netcdf and extract values** (masked_nc_shp = ds.variable_name.where(mask ==0).
6. **Save new file in directory** ( masked_nc_shp.to_netcdf(r'../masked_nc_shp.nc')

Note: This method may not work for older or future versions of regionmask. Plus you can also create region object through  geoDataFrame directly: Please follow: https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/geopandas.html